# How to add @noescape annotation to optional closure

Tags: ios, swift, closures

My function has this signature:

```
func foo(bar: String, baz: ((String) -> ())? = nil)
```

And now I want to make unecessary to escape `self` inside the given closure.
But when I try this:

```
func foo(bar: String, @noescape baz: ((String) -> ())? = nil)
```

The compiler complains:

```
@noescape may only be applied to parameters of function type
```

Is it possible to use it in optional parameters?

Comment: it cannot be used together with an optional function. if you remove the `? = nil` it works.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I know that removing `? = nil` works , let's see if anybody has a different thought

Comment: my compiler complains too. may i know, why do you need this? i think that noescape tells "it is guaranteed not to be needed after the execution is completed". Optional means that the value exists in two different states. if you set nil to optional value, there still exists some reference to it. if closure is Optional the closure can be nil, but still exists the reference to it. noescape seems to be more like 'temporary' ... Very interesting question!!

Comment: I wanna be able to send or not a closure to `foo`, but if I do, I don't wanna need to use `self.` inside my closure. And yes, the closure won't be stored or called asynchronously

Comment: I also have this issue and don't see why @noescape can't be added to optional closures (except insofar as the language designers haven't gotten around to it yet).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Requirements

If your requirements are the following:

- the `baz` param is a `closure`
- the `baz` param is marked with `@noescape` (because you want to omit `self` in the closure code)
- the `baz` param can be omitted during the invocation of `foo`

### Solution

Then you can use the following syntax

```
func foo(bar: String, @noescape baz: ((String) -> ()) = { _ in } ) {

}
```

As you can see the main difference from your code is that:

- here `baz` is not an `optional type` (but it's an "optional parameter")
- and its default value is an `empty closure` not a `nil` value.

### Examples

As you requested you can now pass a closure to `baz` without the need of using `self`

```
class Boo {
    let world = "world"
    func boo() {
        foo("hello") { (something) -> () in
            print(world)
        }
    }
}
```

And you can also omit the `baz` param

```
class Boo {
    let world = "world"
    func boo() {
        foo("hello")
    }
}
```

### Update: using a closure with return type different from Void

In a comment below users `TadeasKriz` asked about how to use this approach with a closure having the return value different the `Void`.

Here it is the solution

```
func foo(bar: String, @noescape baz: ((String) -> (Int)) = { _ in return 0 } ) {

}
```

Here the `baz` param does required a closure with 1 param of type `String` and a return value of type `Int`.
As you can see I added a default value to the param, a closure that does return `0`. Please note that the default closure will never be used so you can replace `0` with any `Int` value you want.

Now you can decide whether to use pass your closure to the `baz` param

```
class Boo {
    let world = "world"
    func boo() {
        foo("hello") { (something) -> Int in
            print(world)
            return 100
        }
    }
}
```

Or, again, you can totally omit the `baz` param.

```
class Boo {
    let world = "world"
    func boo() {
        foo("hello")
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome workaround while Swift doesn't allow the "right way"

Comment: Unfortunately not helpful when having a closure with a return type other than Void.

Comment: For example: `func foo(bar: String, @noescape baz: (String -> MyAwesomeType) = { _ in } ) { }`.

Comment: I ended up workarounding it with: `func foo(bar: String, @noescape baz: (String -> MyAwesomeType?) = { _ in nil } ) { }`

Comment: @TadeasKriz: I added an update to my answer. Now you can use closure with return type different from `Void`.