# What does "{ _ in }" mean in Swift?

Tags: swift

I found some code when I read a book about CoreData in Swift. I am confused about the meaning of the piece of code below. What's the meaning when declaring the closure like `configurationBlock: NSFetchRequest -> () = { _ in }`. especially the meaning of { _ in }.

```
public static func fetchInContext(context: NSManagedObjectContext, @noescape configurationBlock: NSFetchRequest -> () = { _ in }) -> [Self] {
    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: Self.entityName)
    configurationBlock(request)
    guard let result = try! context.executeFetchRequest(request) as? [Self] else { fatalError("Fetched objects have wrong type") }
    return result
}
```

Comment: It's a default empty closure used to work around the fact that you can't assign `@noescape` to an optional closure argument. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33779777/how-to-add-noescape-annotation-to-optional-closure

Comment: @Kurt1018 Please undelete the question I answered. I went to a lot of trouble to answer that question. Deleting an answered question is rude (and can get you banned from asking questions on SO). You should _accept_ my answer to _reward_ me, not delete your answer to punish me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is an empty closure that takes one parameter. In its fullest form, a closure looks like:

```
{ parameter: Type -> ReturnType in 
  // Stuff it does
}
```

If `ReturnType` is void (no return), then it can be left out. If `Type` can be inferred, it can be left out. If `parameter` is unused, it can be replaced with `_`. And if there's no body, there's no body. So you wind up with just this when you're done:

```
{ _ in }
```

In this specific case:

```
configurationBlock: NSFetchRequest -> () = { _ in })
```

`configurationBlock` is a function that takes an `NSFetchRequest` and returns nothing, and its default value is a closure that does nothing. This lets you make `configurationBlock` optional without having to wrap it up in an `Optional`. (I go back and forth about which approach I like better, but both are fine.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation. I am totally understand that, and then read something about the function with default parameter. Looks like I still have a long way to go with new Swift Language.