# Default Parameter Value for Function Type as Parameter Type in Swift 3

Tags: swift, parameter-passing, default-parameters, function-parameter

I want to pass a function to call inside the completion block if I need to, but I do not know how to set a default parameter for a function.

```
 func showAlert(controllerTitle: String, message: String, actionTitle: String, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle = .alert, actionStyle: UIAlertActionStyle = .default, funcToCall: () -> ()){
     let alert = UIAlertController(title: controllerTitle, message: message, preferredStyle: preferredStyle)
     alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: actionTitle, style: actionStyle, handler: {(action) -> Void in 
         funcToCall()
 }))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: {() -> Void in })
 }
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking – are you looking to assign a default function value (that does nothing) to the `funcToCall:` parameter? If so, compare http://stackoverflow.com/q/33779777/2976878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a question should provide a code block as specific as possible.

### The question

So, you have a function `foo` which accepts a parameter of type closure and you want to provide a `default value` right?

### The solution

Here's the code

```
func foo(completion: ()->() = { _ in print("Default completion") }) {
    completion()
}
```

### Testing

Now you can call `foo` passing your own closure

```
foo { print("Hello world") } // Hello world
```

Or using using the default param

```
foo() // Default completion
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a default parameter to a function like so

```
func functionToCall(message: String = "You message") {
    print(message)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have removed all parameters from `showAlert` but the `funcToCall` just to show the way how you can provide default parameter for a function:

```
extension UIViewController {

    private static func defaultFuncToCall() {
        //
    }

    func showAlert(funcToCall: @escaping () -> () = UIViewController.defaultFuncToCall) {
        //
    }
}
```